# add e-mail recipient into php script

Tags: php, email, joomla3.0

CC or forward is not possible to set on mailserver for authorisation mail sent by Joomla itself, but we'd like to store these e-mails.
Question is: how to set it in php of specific plugin? (plugin is sending these e-mails)
code:

```
        // send auth email to user who signed ...
    if ($signature_verification = (int)$this->settings->get('security.signature_verification', 0)) {
        // unpublished, visitor must verify it first
        $this->db->set('published', 0);

        $config = JFactory::getConfig();
        $from = $config->get('mailfrom', '');
        $fromname = $config->get('fromname', '');

        $recipient = (string)$this->db->get('email', '');
```

When I replace last line wth: *$recipient = ('my@email.com')*, then I get that message, but i want one for visitor and **copy** for me.
Thanks for advice

---

OK, actually this piece of code initiates sending of that mail:

```
                if (
                $this->sendMail(
                    $from,
                    $fromname,
                    $recipient,
                    $subject,
                    $body
                ) !== true
            ) {
                throw new phpmailerException(JText::_('PLG_CONTENT_CDPETITIONS_EMAIL_SEND_FAILED'), 500);
            }
```

When I make copy of that code, paste it below, and replace *$recipient* with my e-mail, it works: I have the same message delivered on both adresses. But I need it have it like CC (carbon copy) and have original recipient adress in header of mail, which is delivered to me.

Comment: Without the need to change any of the module code, you could try to add more recipients, delimited by a comma (,): _my@email.com,copy@exaple.com_. The email would not be sent _CC_, but _TO_. So, the original recipient would see the copy recipient too.

Comment: BUT: First recipient is always loaded dynamicaly, second one (me) is static - note last line of code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built in mailer methods for Joomla:

```
$msg = "This is my email message.";
$subject = "Database Update Email";
$to = (string)$this->db->get('email');
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$fromemail = $config->get('mailfrom');
$fromname = $config->get('fromname');
$from = array($fromemail,$fromname);

$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
$mailer->setSender($from);
$mailer->addRecipient($to);
$mailer->addRecipient('you1@yourdomain.com');
$mailer->addRecipient('you2@yourdomain.com');
$mailer->addCC('you3@yourdomain.com');
$mailer->addBCC('you4@yourdomain.com');
$mailer->setSubject($subject);
$mailer->setBody($msg);
$mailer->isHTML();
$mailer->send();
```

This should use PHP to send an HTML email to whomever you want and copy other users on the email through either direct send, CC, or BCC depending on which method you use.

Comment: when i paste $mailer = JFactory::getMailer(); before, it has no errors, but sending mails only to visitor again and not copy for me

Comment: Are you adding in this line a second time? That will specify your second recipient. And can you post your full code with the changes?

$mailer->addRecipient('you2@yourdomain.com');

Comment: `code
        // send auth email to user who signed ...
    if ($signature_verification = (int)$this->settings->get('security.signature_verification', 0)) {
        // unpublished, visitor must verify it first
        $this->db->set('published', 0);

        $config = JFactory::getConfig();
        $from = $config->get('mailfrom', '');
        $fromname = $config->get('fromname', '');

        $recipient = (string)$this->db->get('email', ''); 
        $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
        $mailer->addRecipient('MyName@gmail.com');`
        
 ... works for original recipient only

Comment: What is your mail setting in global configuration? Php mailer? Send mail? Smtp?

Comment: I am very sorry for confusion, I had edited my original question. ↑ ↑ ↑  I did not know, what to ask exactly.

Comment: Ok it appears that you custom wrote a mail function for sending that email out. If that is the case I would say try to use the suggestion that @hherger commented but change it just a little. Try concatenating your email address onto the end of the recipient with a semicolon like this:

$recipient = (string)$this->db->get('email', '').';me@myemail.com';

so if you echo $recipient it shoud look like:

youruser@fromdatabase.com;me@myemail.com

Comment: Then I get system message by Joomla: E-mail notification failed.

Comment: maybe try this one:

Store the recipients in an array and then just loop through it firing your email script each time?

$recipients = array((string)$this->db->get('email', ''),'me@myemail.com');

foreach($recipients as $recipient){ //your email logic}

Comment: This finally works. After 3 days of mind blowing work, You saved me. Thanks very much.